# JasperReports (6.20.1) dependency not satisfied in Java project : Failure to find com.github.librepdf:openpdf:jar:1.3.30.jaspersoft.1

Tags: maven, jasper-reports

When trying to import our Java Spring Maven project for generating Jasper reports in IntelliJ IDEA, we get the following error:

`Failure to find com.github.librepdf:openpdf:jar:1.3.30.jaspersoft.1`

We're using the latest release version `6.20.1` of JasperReports:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>6.20.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I tried to look up `openpdf` in the [Maven Central Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/6.20.1), but it looks like version `1.3.30.jaspersoft.1` doesn't exist; there is indeed  version `1.3.30` but without the `.jaspersoft.1` suffix:

[image]

If I explicitely add version `1.3.30` of `com.github.librepdf:openpdf` in my `pom.xml`, Maven install is successful, but the warning is still there and if I reload the Maven project in IntelliJ, the error mentioned at the beginning of this post pops up again.

Can you please help me out? Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Jaspersoft have published these third-party dependencies in their jfrog repo. Add `https://jaspersoft.jfrog.io/jaspersoft/jaspersoft-repo` to the list of repositories that you search.

Comment: I understand, many thanks. We'll retrieve it from there and put it into our internal repository.